# How to convert part of columns to row by using pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like this:

```
A      B      C      D      E ...
a1     b1     c1     d1     e1 ...
a2     b2     c2     d2     e2 ...
```

I want to change to:

```
A      B      Name  Value
a1     b1     D     d1 
a1     b1     E     e1
...

a2     b2     D     d2
a2     b2     E     e2
```

Is it possible to do with pandas?
(Column A & B is the unique union column, column C is the one we don't need any more)

Comment: @Datanovice I feel like this is melt , df.melt(['A','B'])

Comment: @WeNYoBen now that I look at it again you are right thank you sir